# unique ID for multi tabel? (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, uniqueidentifier

I have a table 'article' and each of these articles belongs to one of three different topics (topic_a, b and c). I also have a table for each of these topics with various fields. How can I connect these the best way?

I was thinking that, since every topic has many articles, I would add a topic_ID field to each article, but the ID would not be unique unless I use UUID. Would it make sense to use UUID in this case or is there a better way?

Another idea was to add three topic ID fields to each article and just fill the appropriate one (topic_a_ID, topic_b_ID,..) and leave the other two empty. But this also seems not right.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your story mine first idea what crosses mine mind was.

```
**article.** 
 article_id 
 article_name
 ...
 ...

**topic** 
 topic_id
 article_id
 topic_name
 ...
 ...


**topic_has_many_articles** (many to many relation and your connection table)
  topic_id
  article_id
```

You need to use correct indexing for this to scale well with large datasets.

Comment: Yes, thank you. This seems like a good solution. But I thought that this kind of third table for the relationship is for many-to-many relations. But in my case the each article only has one associated topic. the topics are just in three different tables, i.e. three different id rows.